# Why can i connect from different subnet? Windows 10 PC connected to Ubuntu PC

Tags: linux, networking, ip

Ok, so i connected a linux laptop to windows 10 laptop with ethernet cable.

**Windows machine**

I specified manual IP settings for windows laptop ethernet adapter to be:

IP address 192.168.255.126

Subnet mask 255.255.255.0

i left default gateway empty.

Then i started TCP listener using windows subsystem for linux:

wsl nc -l 192.168.255.126 1234 -v

**Linux machine**

I run ifconfig to check eth0

IP address 169.254.10.116

Subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Then i run:

nc 192.168.255.126 1234

And i have an connection.

The question is why?
This does not work the other way around, windows laptop can't ping or connect to server hosted on linux machine.

Is windows implementation of subnet masking somehow flawed?

Comment: What source/destination IP addresses (and MAC addresses) do you see on the actual packets that are being sent and received?

Comment: @user1686 I checked with wireshark that the packets were sent with those exact IP addresses. i run ifconfig (linux) and ipconfig /all (windows), and the same mac addresses were on the packets and network interfaces.

Comment: Are you using direct connect or going through a router? Having no router will explain it.

Comment: Direct connection. Ethernet cable from laptop to laptop. How does that explain it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using direct connect and not going through a router, which is the reason that
this works. You are using here the
[data link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer)
or layer 2 of the OSI model of computer networking, which is not concerned
with higher-level concepts like addressing.

The network adapter on each computer sends out its packets to the entire network.
Each listening computer will pick up the packages addressed to itself and discard
others.

The Windows computer has an IP address and will answer packages addressed
to itself, evidently not being very strict about the source IP address.

The Linux computer has tried to find a DHCP server and failed,
so assigned itself a
[Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)
starting with `169.254`. It is evidently more strict than Windows about
which network packages it will answer.